# what's wrong with this string concatenation function

Tags: c

why doesn't this code work properly? 
this is K&R exercise **5-3**

```
char str[20]= "Hello world";
char str2[5] = "xxx";
int main(void) {
    strcat(str, str2);
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}

void strcat(char *s, char *a) {
    while (*s++);
    while (*s++ = *a++);
}
```

Comment: Hint: where does `s` point to right after `while(*s++);` ?

Comment: Another hint: read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You'll get a job after doing all exercises in this book.

Comment: i check whether if null mnemonic terminates loop and gives me a pointer to the last address then i will add content of second address to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `while(*s++);` still increments `s` even when it hits the NULL string terminator before exiting to the next statement.  Try:

```
while (*s) {
    s++;
}
```

So that `s` does not get incremented when `s` becomes NULL.  That way, the first character of `a` can overwrite the NULL terminator for `s`.

Postfix increment/decrement have high precedence, but the actual increment or decrement of the operand is delayed (to be accomplished sometime before the statement completes execution). So in the statement y = x * z++; the current value of z is used to evaluate the expression (i.e., z++ evaluates to z) and z only incremented after all else is done (http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

Comment: this gives me right answer and also is the same to my last one 
`while(s[++i]);`
`while(s[i++] = a[j++]);`

Comment: this works properly
`while(*s)
        s++;
    while(*s++ = *a++);`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while(*s++)
```

to

```
while(*s && *(++s));
```

so that s first increments and then gets checked, in order to have the pointer to the last address.

Comment: it works properly but why prefix works and post doesn't? 
then `*s++` according to precedence of operators in c `s++` is performed first then unary `*` Right to Left .?

Comment: This won't work if `s` is an empty string, with first character equal to `\0`.

Comment: Edited to work with empty string. 

See this about operators precedence.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: i guess postfix is suitable as it increment s after its value is used, on the other hand, prefix increment first then assigned value.